# Prove that if $f$ is continuous on $c$ , then $sup\{f(x): x \in I , x \lt c\}=inf\{f(x):x \in I , x>c\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question :

Assume that $f$ is an increasing function defined on interval $I$ and $c \in I$.
Also Assume that $f$ is continuous on $c$.

Prove that $sup\{f(x): x \in I , x \lt c\}=inf\{f(x):x \in I , x>c\}$.

Note :

I believe that since $f$ is increasing, so the more $x$'s value gets close to $c$, the more $f(x)$ gets close to $f(c)$. I think that the statement is so obvious ... But i don't know how to write a formal proof ... Also, in my reasoning, i didn't use the fact that $f$ is continuous on $c$.  Is my reasoning true? How should i write a formal proof ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will show that

$$f(c)=\inf\{f(x):x \in I , x>c\}.$$ Since $f$ is increasing we have that $f(c)<f(x)$ for $x\in I, x>c.$ Thus $f(c)$ is a lower bound of $\{f(x):x \in I , x>c\},$ from where

$$f(c)\le \inf\{f(x):x \in I , x>c\}.$$ Now, since $f$ is continuous at $c$ we have that $$\rm{given}\: \epsilon>0\exists \delta >0 : c<x<c+\delta\implies f(x)<f(c)+\epsilon.$$ Thus,

$$\inf\{f(x):x \in I , x>c\}<f(c)+\epsilon.$$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we conclude that $$\inf\{f(x):x \in I , x>c\}\le f(c).$$

Show in a similar way that $$f(c)=\sup\{f(x):x \in I , x<c\}$$ and you are done.